# Why is import enquiries not working in my Python code?

Tags: python, crash

I'm trying to import inquiries from https://pypi.org/project/enquiries/ but my code is just crashing I'm still fairly new to coding so maybe I'm missing something obvious. I've made sure to run the installation in the cmd and updated pip but there is still some error going on. Any ideas on why this is happening? Or can someone let me know how to see the exact error that is happening rather than it just crashing on install. Thank you many thanks and all help is much appreciated!

`#imports`
`import os`
`import sys`
`import random`
`import enquiries`

`actions = ["Attack" , "Heal" ]`
`gameState = False`
`pchp = 10`
`cpuhp = 10`

`while gameState == False: print("Your hp is" , + pchp) print("Your Opponents hp is" , + cpuhp) print ("Pick an action!") print (actions [0],"-",actions [1]) choice = input() choice = choice.title() os.system('cls')`

```
if choice == "Attack":
    print("You deal 1 damage")
    cpuhp = cpuhp - 1
    pass
elif choice == "Heal":
    if pchp < 10:
        print("You regain 2 hp")
        pchp = pchp + 2
        pass
    else:
        os.system('cls')
        print("You are already at full hp!")
        input("Press Enter to return to options")
        os.system('cls')
        continue
else:
    print("invalid input")
    input("Press Enter to return to options")
    os.system('cls')
    continue #reiterates while loop

input("Press Enter to Exit")
```

input("Press Enter to Exit")

Comment: Check output of `pip freeze` to ensure the package is installed correctly

Comment: Just checked, it's the right version

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Just added it to the main post